# How to automate LSF batch job submission through a loop over one argument to run a R script?

Tags: r, loops, arguments, jobs, lsf

I have thousands of files and folders with the same structure in a main directory path. I am trying to improve the processing time of a R script by automating several LSF batch jobs using arguments. I have some experience with R but no experience with batch file and other language associated.

**Description of the structure of my folders:**

In the main directory, I have several folders that are named based on the year and each of these folders contain other folders based on the name of a model. The folders that are named based on model contained the files I compute.

```
                               year        model

                                     ----- A
                           |----1980|
                           |         ----- B
main directory path -------|
                           |         ----- A
                           |----1981|
                                     ----- B
```

**R script**

I have a R script where I have two parameters "year" and "model" that will be my arguments. I create a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)

#Creation of raster files that that allow to create files. Here, I only create two rasters that should be place in one folder model. 

r1= raster(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, res = 0.5,
       xmn = -1.5, xmx = 1.5, ymn = -1.5, ymx = 1.5,
       vals = 0.3)

 r2= raster(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, res = 0.5,
       xmn = -1.5, xmx = 1.5, ymn = -1.5, ymx = 1.5,
       vals = 0.1)

 which_year=arg[1]
 years<- c("1980", "1981")
 year<- years(which_year)

 which_model=arg[2]
 models<- c("A"  ,"B")
 model<- models(which_model)

     setwd(file.path("directory_path",year, model)


pr<- stack(r1, r2)
mean<- mean(pr)

writeRaster(mean, file.path("directory_path",year, model_name,  'stackr1r2.tif'))
```

**Batch code**

My concern is to implement a loop in the batch script. I would like to automate batch job submission through a loop over years and models that will allow me to go the adequate directory. However, I have no ideas how to do that.

I know that the structure should be something like that:

```
do from model = 1, nmodel
do from year =1, nyear

bsub -n 1 -W 3600 "Rscript mycode.R year model"
enddo
enddo
```

Thanks for any help and I hope I was clear in my explanations as I do not have the technical vocabulary!